# Rendering multiple items with different props React ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, ecmascript-6, material-ui

<---------------------***EDIT***------------------------>

I was hoping for a method, where I only needed a single onChange function, however it did not seem like any of the answers provided that. However, I was wrong. Thanks to [Kind user's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44863047/4955969) I was able to understand that it is possible (although not immediately, as you can tell from the comments). Therefore I have created my own version, which I have tested and is working.

We have the class `CheckboxesField.js`

```
import React from 'react'
import Checkbox from 'material-ui/Checkbox'
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider'

const CheckboxesField = props => {
  const checkboxes = props.allPossibleCheckboxes.map(checkbox =>
    <Checkbox style={{ width: '20%' }}
      checked={props.checked.includes(checkbox)}
      onCheck={props.onCheck}
      key={checkbox}
      label={checkbox}
      id={checkbox}
      iconStyle={{ fill: '#000' }} />)
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider>
        <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
          {checkboxes}
        </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    )
  }

export default CheckboxesField
```

and class `index.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import CheckboxesField from './CheckboxesField'

class Index extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      checked: ["two", "five"],
      allPossible: ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"],
    }
    this.onCheck = this.onCheck.bind(this)
  }

  onCheck(e, v) {
    const checked = this.state.checked
    if (v) {
      checked.push(e.target.id)
    } else {
      checked.splice(checked.indexOf(e.target.id), 1)
    }
    this.setState({ checked })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="index">
        <CheckboxesField
          allPossibleCheckboxes={this.state.allPossible}
          checked={this.state.checked}
          onCheck={this.onCheck}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Index
ReactDOM.render(<Index />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

By manipulating 2 arrays, one with all the possible checkboxes and 1 with the selected value, we can use a single onCheck function and we do not need a state for each checkbox.

The reason I wanted this, is I want to get the checked fields from a database and by doing it this way, one can simply add another checkbox possibility to the db and no code needs to be changed, for it to work.

---

***Original question***

I am trying to create a field of material ui checkboxes.

I know I could do

```
<div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
      <Checkbox style={{ width: '20%' }} checked={{ props.checkedOne }} onCheck={{ props.onCheckOne }} key={"one"} label={"one"} iconStyle={{ fill: '#000' }} />
      <Checkbox style={{ width: '20%' }} checked={{ props.checkedTwo }} onCheck={{ props.onCheckTwo }} key={"two"} label={"two"} iconStyle={{ fill: '#000' }} />
      .
      .
      .
</div>
```

for however many checkboxes I need. This however gets annoying and involves a lot of writing.

Therefore I have a CheckboxesFields class which maps Checkboxes based on a prop called labelsList, which contains a list of type `String`

```
import React from 'react'
import Checkbox from 'material-ui/Checkbox'
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider'

const CheckboxesField = props => {
  const checkboxes = props.labelsList.map(label => <Checkbox style={{ width: '20%' }} key={label} label={label} iconStyle={{ fill: '#000' }} />)
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider>
        <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
          {checkboxes}
        </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    )
  }

export default CheckboxesField
```

This is then called in App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import CheckboxesField from './CheckboxesField'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <CheckboxesField labelsList={["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

This works but unlike the first example if I pass the props `onCheck` and `checked` it will apply to every single checkbox. However I want each checkbox to be controlled individually.

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: pass the data in object like `labelsList={[{key: 1,checked: checkedOne}.....]}`

Comment: Thanks Slim! Worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass not only label to the props but also the callback functions

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import CheckboxesField from './CheckboxesField'

let myfunc1 = () => { console.log("Hello World!") };

let labelsList = [
    {
       onCheck: myfunc1,
       checked: true,
       label: '1',
    },...
];    

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <CheckboxesField labels={labelsList} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

later in the checkboxes generator call the passed callbacks like this.

```
import React from 'react'
import Checkbox from 'material-ui/Checkbox'
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider'

const CheckboxesField = props => {
  const checkboxes = props.labelsList.map(label => <Checkbox 
                             style={{ 
                                   width: '20%' 
                              }} 
                              key={label.label} 
                              label={label.label}
                              onCheck={label.onCheck}
                              checked={label.checked}
                              iconStyle={{ fill: '#000' }} 
   />);
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider>
        <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
          {checkboxes}
        </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    )
  }

export default CheckboxesField
```

Answer (score 1):

Suggested approach:

**`app.js`**

```
class App extends Component {

  handleCheckbox(event, isChecked, id) {
    console.log(isChecked, id); // will determine which checkbox was changed
                                // and what is it's actual state (checked or not)
  }

  labelList = [1,2,3,4,5]; // rather temporary solution

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.labelList.map(element => (
          <CheckboxesField 
            key={element} 
            label={element} 
            onChange={this.handleCheckbox} 
          />
        )}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**`Checkbox component`**

```
export class CheckboxesField extends React.PureComponent {

  handleCheck = (event, isInputChecked) => {
    this.props.onChange(event, isInputChecked, this.props.label);
  };

  render() {
    return (
          <Checkbox
            style={{width: '20%'}}
            label={this.props.label}
            iconStyle={{fill: '#000'}}
            onCheck={this.handleCheck}
          />
    )}
}
```

Comment: I am not sure how I can use this. I need to be able to clearly identify which checkboxes have been checked and send that data to a database. I also need to check some boxes depending on data from the database on mount. I am not sure how I could do that with this code.

Comment: @Cornelius `handleCheckbox` function returns an `id` of actually checked checkbox and `isChecked` boolean value if it's checked or not. It may looks a lil' bit complicated for you, but just spend some time and check it out thoroughly, it's the best possible solution imo. Other solutions are hard-coded or *jQuery-like*. **Material-UI** has it's own, build-in function to handle check event, there's no need to make your own function, to handle it.

Comment: I get that, but how would I go about finding which checkboxes should be checked when the component is mounting, since I need to call onCheck to get the state and id, since they aren't actually stored as states.

Comment: @Cornelius But what's the point of storing the data? You need some of them to be checked automatically before mounting the component?

Comment: @Cornelius Here's the thing. If you want to specify if some of the checkboxes have to be checked, you will need to use an array of objects. Material-UI checkbox accepts it as a *checked* prop. If you would spend few minutes and read thoroughly the docs for UI checkbox, you would know everything you need.

Comment: You were absolutely right. I didn't understand what you meant. By using the id, as you mentioned, you don't need to manipulate the state and can use a single onCheck, as I have shown in my edit to this question. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Cornelius I'm glad that I could help you. You can mark my answer as the best one, if you think it worths it.

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested, you have to provide list of not only labels,but also check state and appropriate onCLick function for each checkbox something like:

```
const cbData = [ {label: "hm", checked: .. , onClick:..}, {label: "hm", checked: .. , onClick} ... ]
```

Label and checked are not problematic, onClick is a bit more involved since you actually need different function for each checkbox. This can be accomplished with currying or kind of function generator function, if you will. Like in:

```
const onClickGenerator = (checkboxId) => () => console.log("clicked cbox " + checkboxId)
```

if you call `onClickGenerator("myId")` you will get a function that takes no arguments, and when called this function displays `clicked cbox myId`

So armed with that we can generate array of checkbox components from the cbData (which does not need onClick inside):

```
cbData.map((label) => (<Checkbox 
                             style={{ 
                                   width: '20%' 
                              }} 
                              key={label.label} 
                              label={label.label}
                              onCheck={onClickGenerator(label.label)}
                              {...(label.checked ? ({checked:true}) : ({}))}
                              iconStyle={{ fill: '#000' }}
```